# Does combineLatest not fire becuase of the behaviorSubject?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, rxjs6

The Following code is from my service component. It requires a user observable and the data to submit in a BehaviorSubject. I call `form.service.formToSubmit$.next(form);` to update it. because combineLatest also fires when the user observable emits I do a check if the formToSubmit is not null and it is set to null after it is submitted. But its not firing when I update formToSubmit. I have tried just bout everything.

```
     this.formToSubmit$ = new BehaviorSubject<Forms>(null);  
    constructor(){
    this.updateForm();

}
    updateForm(){
            combineLatest(this.authService.user$, this.formToSubmit$).pipe(
                switchMap(([user, form]) =>{
                    if(form == null) return;
                    return this.afs.collection('networks').doc(user.activeNetworkProfile.id).collection('companyProfiles').doc(user.activeCompanyProfile.id).collection('inspectionForms').doc(form.id).set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(form))).then(success=>{
                        this.formToSubmit$.next(null);
                    }).catch(err=>{
                        this.formToSubmit$.next(null);  
                    });
                })
            );
        }
```

This is the previous code that worked just fine.

```
updateFormdd(form: Forms){
        return Observable.create(observer=>{
            this.authService.user$.subscribe(user=>{
                this.afs.collection('networks').doc(user.activeNetworkProfile.id).collection('companyProfiles').doc(user.activeCompanyProfile.id).collection('inspectionForms').doc(form.id).set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(form))).then(success=>{
                    observer.next(success);
                    observer.complete();
                }).catch(err=>{
                    observer.err(err);
                });
            })
        })
    }
```

But ultimately the goal is to figure out how to do the above function but allow me to combine up to 3 observable like in the following function.

```
  updateInspection(){

            combineLatest(this.authService.user$, this.equipmentId$, this.inspectionToSubmit$).pipe(
                switchMap(([user, equipmentId, form]) =>{
                    if(form == null) return;
                    return this.afs.collection('networks').doc(user.activeNetworkProfile.id).collection('companyProfiles').doc(user.activeCompanyProfile.id).collection('equipment').doc(equipmentId).set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(form))).then(success=>{
                        this.formToSubmit$.next(null);
                    }).catch(err=>{
                        this.formToSubmit$.next(null);
                    });
                })
            );

    }
```

I just want to ensure Im using observable's properly. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of the difference between your two pieces of code is the "subscribe".

The working version had a subscription. Since your observables are cold observables, they will not emit until something is subscribed to them.

Figure out where you want to consume that observable and then add the subscription there.

```
this.formToSubmit$ = new BehaviorSubject<Forms>(null);  
constructor(){
let mySubscription = this.updateForm().subscribe(
    (dataFromCombineLatest) => {
        // This subscription should cause the code inside the combine to fire
    }
);
```

Also, if this is inside a "component", I do recommend to run that bit in the "onInit" instead of the constructor (I like my constructor code to be lean).

Comment: So the behaviorSubject is a cold observable it will not fire off combineLatest? So how do I got bout using multiple observables? Should I nest subscriptions? For example in the updateInspection()

Comment: If there are no subscriptions on the chain, i.e. if nothing is subscribed to the values on the observable then your emission code will not be hit.
It is not your combination that is not working is that nothing is subscribing to it. "combineLatest" returns an observable, and I can't see anything being subscribed to it. 

Try something like this, see if the code in the combine fires:


    this.formToSubmit$ = new BehaviorSubject<Forms>(null);  
    constructor(){
    let updateFormSubscription = 
    this.updateForm().subscribe((dataFromCombineLatest) => { // do something here });

Comment: I added some expanded explanation to the response, should be more readable than the comment.

Comment: I changed it to the following,  but it also triggers when the user observable updates. Setting the formToSubmit to null and checking if null can fix that but seems dirty. has to be a better way. `constructor(){
    let mySubscription = this.updateForm().subscribe(
        (dataFromCombineLatest) => {
            //this is where I will write to the database;
        }
    );
}

updateForm(){
    return combineLatest(this.authService.user$, this.formToSubmit$);
} `

Comment: Do you want only one emission? In that case you may want to use "zip" instead of "combineLatest". See http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

Comment: Neither work, if i add the database call into the combineLatest it does not fire. But if I add a console.log(dataFromCombineLatest); it works perfectly.